# Puzzle on a Pie Crust

Tags: word, visual, letters

Can you find the hidden message in this pie crust?

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see:

> WOULD YOU LIKE A SLICE OF PI?

...if:

> we take steps of the digits of Pi:
>
> ```
> --31---41----5--------9-2-----6----5--3----5-------8--------9------7--------9--3-2--3-------8---4-----6-2
> UBWOIBPULCEVADZRPZRCMTYHOTIVJFUCBPULOKIWWPEKNFNFMHQEDCXXPUENARSTVHGSGKEZTNVMLBUIWCVNELNOXTFQOJDVFJLVYTPNI
> --WO---UL----D--------Y-O-----U----L--I----K-------E--------A------S--------L--I-C--E-------O---F-----P-I
> ```

Comment: That is correct!